# Highcharts - prevent re-calculation of values when a series is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using a stacked column chart from Highcharts. I calculate my y-axis as percentages `(min:0, max:100)`. When I hide a certain series, I would like the percentages on the other series to remain the same (no re-calculation). But the animation and re-attaching of the remaining series types can remain as they are. 
I just want to avoid percentages changing when some series is omitted from the legend.

You can check my example in this fiddle [fiddle_sample](http://jsfiddle.net/khalidcawl/x8eev53o/1/).
The  legendItemClick function is where I put my comment.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to iterate over your series and calculate your total stack manually. Two simple examples: http://jsfiddle.net/x8eev53o/3/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/x8eev53o/5/

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you @Grzegorz. Appreciate it. Why not add it as an answer so that I can accept it. It will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, it is possible to calculate your points manually using dataLabels.formatter function:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var total = 0;
      var x = this.point.x;
      Highcharts.each(this.series.chart.userOptions.series, function(s) {
        Highcharts.each(s.data, function(p, pointX) {
          if (pointX === x) {
            total += p;
          }
        })
      });
      if (this.percentage == 0 || !this.percentage)
        return ''
      else
        return Math.round(this.y * 100 / total) + '%';
    },
    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
  }
```

I have prepared two examples how it should be possible to make your chart. You can find these examples in links below:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8eev53o/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/x8eev53o/3/